# How to transform multiple config files using multiple tokenize.config files using qetza.xdttransform.xdttransform-task.xdttransform

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an azure devops release (legacy interface, not yaml), where I need to transform 5 different config files corresponding to 5 different published artifacts.  Can this be done with a single transformation, I am currently using 5 different qetza.xdttransform.xdttransform-task.xdttransform tasks to transform each file one at a time.

So I have:
Working Folder : $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/sources/A1
Transformations: app.tokenize.config => A1.exe.config

Working Folder : $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/sources/1A
Transformations: app.tokenize.config => 1A.exe.config

Working Folder : $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/sources/Three
Transformations: app.tokenize.config => Three.exe.config

Working Folder : $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/sources/4a
Transformations: app.tokenize.config => 4a.exe.config

Working Folder : $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/sources/ConsoleApp1
Transformations: app.tokenize.config => ConsoleApp1.exe.config

So can this be combined into a single task that runs for all paths?

Comment: You can add all of the transformations with new line, [XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform) looks to support that or am I missing something?

Comment: @Sibtain: make that an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XDT Transform task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform) already supports adding all the transformations with a new line

[image]